# Multiple DataSources in Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring 4 one could use BatchConfigurer to point the JobRepository to the intended DataSource.

But in Spring 5, I am lost.

- I have the spring.datasource.* properties in the application.properties and
- configured my business datasource anonymously.

However, I still get the error that the database type could not be found.
I am grateful for every hint to the right direction.

Comment: You need information for each separate data source you require.  Spring is complaining that you haven't given it the information.  Believe Spring and provide it.  I don't know what "configured anonymously" means.  Sounds wrong.  Be explicit and configure them all individually.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Batch 5, you can specify the datasource to use in the job repository in one of two ways, depending on the configuration approach you use (annotation-based or programmatic):

- If you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, then you need to set the `dataSourceRef` attribute to point the the datasource bean you want
- If you use `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, then you can override `getDataSource()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample config that lets you run your batch application with additional datasource:

```java
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    private final MyProcessor processor;

    private final MyReader reader;

    private final MyWriter writer;


    public BatchConfig(MyProcessor processor, MyReader reader, MyWriter writer) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step transformStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("processingStepz", jobRepository)
                .<ProcessingItem, ProcessingItem>chunk(20, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, Step transformStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(transformStep)
                .build();
    }

    /*
      Expose embedded datasource and transaction manager beans with "dataSource" and "transactionManager" names.
    */
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
//    @BatchDataSource
    public DataSource h2Datasource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = builder
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("batch_db")
                .build();
        return embeddedDatabase;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    protected PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(h2Datasource());

        return manager;
    }
}
```

In a separate config file you may configure your "main" datasource:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = { MyEntityRepository.class },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "customEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager"
)
public class CustomDatasourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String ddlAuto;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource customDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",
                "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
                "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ddlAuto);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(customDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.plainbatch.model");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("customPersistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(properties);

        return builder
                .dataSource(backboneDataSource())
                .packages(MyEntity.class)
                .persistenceUnit("customPersistenceUnit")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TransactionManager customTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(customDataSource());
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(customEntityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());

        return manager;
    }

}
```